# Inherit Datatable object

Tags: c#, class, object, inheritance

I'm working at a C# solution, and  I've got this form which I'm populating my txtboxes, using a DataTable object and then retrieving the information trought the row number, the problem is, I've got navigation buttons, next and previous, and I just noticed that when I call my function to PopulateView(); after I press this buttons, I redo the DB connection, the SQLite query and the datatable fill.

I feel ashamed but, I really don't know where is the proper place to put this function in order that my other functions in this form receive these objects.

My Code:

```
namespace X_Project{
public partial class Cad_Prod : Form
{
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn1 = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=X.s3db");
    int prodstart = 0;
    public Cad_Prod()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Cad_Prod_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void PopulateView()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Cad_Prod";
        string query2 = "SELECT * FROM Cat";
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn1))
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(comm))
            using (SQLiteCommand comm2 = new SQLiteCommand(query2, conn1))
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(comm2))
            {
                conn1.Open();
                DataTable produtos = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(produtos);
                DataTable categoria = new DataTable();
                adapter2.Fill(categoria);

                int auxCat = int.Parse(produtos.Rows[prodstart].ItemArray[4].ToString()) - 1;

                txtProdutoNome.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                txtProdutoPreco.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                txtProdutoQtd.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart].ItemArray[3].ToString();
                cbbCategoria.Text = categoria.Rows[auxCat].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnAvancar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prodstart = prodstart + 1;
        PopulateView();
    }

    private void btnVoltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prodstart = prodstart - 1;
        PopulateView();
    }
}
```

the code above works, but no the way I want it, what i really would like to do is:

```
namespace X_Project\
{

public partial class Cad_Prod : Form
    {

    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn1 = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=X.s3db");
    int prodstart = 0;
    public Cad_Prod()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Cad_Prod_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string query = "SELECT * FROM Cad_Prod";
        string query2 = "SELECT * FROM Cat";
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn1))
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(comm))
            using (SQLiteCommand comm2 = new SQLiteCommand(query2, conn1))
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(comm2))
                {
                conn1.Open();
                DataTable produtos = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(produtos); // I would like this to be inherited
                DataTable categoria = new DataTable();
                adapter2.Fill(categoria); // I would like this to be inherited
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    private void PopulateView()
    {


                int auxCat = int.Parse(produtos.Rows[prodstart].ItemArray[4].ToString()) - 1;

                txtProdutoNome.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                txtProdutoPreco.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                txtProdutoQtd.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart].ItemArray[3].ToString();
                cbbCategoria.Text = categoria.Rows[auxCat].ItemArray[1].ToString();

    }

    private void btnAvancar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prodstart = prodstart + 1;
        PopulateView();
    }

    private void btnVoltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prodstart = prodstart - 1;
        PopulateView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the dataTables in form level property variables that use the "Lazy initializer" pattern, i.e., where they are coded so they will only call the database once, and populate a static private variable with the datatable that first time; every successive call will just read the private variable and skip the database call.

```
public partial class Cad_Prod : Form
{
   private static readonly SQLiteConnection conn1 =
         new SQLiteConnection(("data source=X.s3db");
   private static DataTable produtos;
   private static DataTable produtos;
   private static DataTable AutoDataTable => 
      produtos?? (produtos = GetAutos());           
   private static DataTable CategoryDataTable => 
      categoria ?? (categoria = GetCategories());            

   int prodstart = 0;
   public Cad_Prod() { InitializeComponent(); }

   public void Cad_Prod_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  {  }
   private static DataTable GetAutos()
   {
      string query = "SELECT * FROM Cad_Prod";
      try
      {
          using (SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn1))
          using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(comm))
          {
            conn1.Open();
            DataTable produtos = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(produtos); 
            return produtos;
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Erro", 
          MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
          throw;
      }
   }
   private static DataTable GetCategories()
   {
      string query2 = "SELECT * FROM Cat";
      try
      {
         using (SQLiteCommand comm2 = new SQLiteCommand(query2, conn1))
         using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(comm2))
            {
            conn1.Open();
            DataTable categoria = new DataTable();
            adapter2.Fill(categoria);
            return categoria;
            }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Erro", 
          MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
          throw;
      }
  }

  private void PopulateView()
  {
     int auxCat = int.Parse(produtos.Rows[prodstart]
            .ItemArray[4].ToString()) - 1;

     txtProdutoNome.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart]
            .ItemArray[1].ToString();
     txtProdutoPreco.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart]
            .ItemArray[2].ToString();
     txtProdutoQtd.Text = produtos.Rows[prodstart]
            .ItemArray[3].ToString();
     cbbCategoria.Text = categoria.Rows[auxCat]
            .ItemArray[1].ToString();
  }

  private void btnAvancar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    prodstart = prodstart + 1;
    PopulateView();
  }

  private void btnVoltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    prodstart = prodstart - 1;
    PopulateView();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey charles, iI'm quite new to C#, but I believe that there are a few mistakes at the code you gave me, could you review your answer please? 

also, i'm receiving errors at the GetCategories and GetAutos, first at the private static DataTable CategoryDataTable => categoria ?? (categoria = GetCategories());   visual studio, says that an object reference is required for the non static....

and at the private DataTable GetAutos() or GetCategories(); 

catch does not return any value and c# wants me to return some type of the type datatable.

thanks again